# CommandLineParser - Use the same switch/flag multiple times

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, command-line-parser

Using the CommandLineParser NuGet, when I run my application with an option like this.

```
myapplication.exe --searchfolder "c:\my great path\"
```

How can I use that options more than once?  For example, if I want to pass in two folders...

1. "c:\my great path"
2. "c:\my other great path"

Currently, I use it like this for the single path given...

```
if (options.Verbose)
{
    m_Verbose = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Verbose mode on.");
}

if (options.SearchFolder != null && options.SearchFolder != "")
{
  Console.WriteLine("Searching folder '{0}'...", options.SearchFolder);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you write two pathes? It's not clear from your code how you obtain even the first path. What is `options`? Please refer to [mcve].

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use the `CommandLineParser` package? For something  like this it may be easier to process `string[] args` yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use something like this:

```
class Options
{
  [Option('r', "read", Required = true, HelpText = "Input files to be processed.")]
  public IEnumerable<string> InputFiles { get; set; }
```

Check the official net fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wrcAxr for the `IEnumerable` usage.

Comment: Awesome!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks

Comment: I would add to this answer for clarity that at the time of writing you could only use the flag once, and then repeat the parameter so for example: execute.exe -flag "a=b" "c=d" you can't use execute.exe -flag "a=b" -flag "c=d" from what I've tried.